# Html.Raw() in ASP.NET MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{int count = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.Resources)
{
    @(count <= 3 ? Html.Raw("<div class=\"resource-row\">").ToString() : Html.Raw("")) 
    // some code
    @(count <= 3 ? Html.Raw("</div>").ToString() : Html.Raw("")) 
    @(count++)

}
```

This code part does not compile, with the following error

```
Error   18  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Web.IHtmlString'   d:\Projects\IRC2011_HG\IRC2011\Views\Home\_AllResources.cshtml  21  24  IRC2011
```

What I must I do?

Comment: ToString will show HTML string in the page. Like "<div></div>".ToString() will show <div></div> instead of adding div element.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`Html.Raw()` returns `IHtmlString`, not the ordinary `string`. So, you cannot write them in opposite sides of `:` operator. Remove that `.ToString()` calling

```
@{int count = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.Resources)
{
    @(count <= 3 ? Html.Raw("<div class=\"resource-row\">"): Html.Raw("")) 
    // some code
    @(count <= 3 ? Html.Raw("</div>") : Html.Raw("")) 
    @(count++)

}
```

By the way, returning `IHtmlString` is the way MVC recognizes html content and does not encode it. Even if it hasn't caused compiler errors, calling `ToString()` would destroy meaning of `Html.Raw()`

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer is correct, but I prefer:

```
@{int count = 0;} 
@foreach (var item in Model.Resources) 
{ 
    @Html.Raw(count <= 3 ? "<div class=\"resource-row\">" : "")  
    // some code 
    @Html.Raw(count <= 3 ? "</div>" : "")  
    @(count++)
}
```

I hope this inspires someone, even though I'm late to the party.

Comment: The only change I would make is to move the string literals into constants and access them by a meaningful name.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't be calling `.ToString()`.

As the error message clearly states, you're writing a conditional in which one half is an `IHtmlString` and the other half is a string.
That doesn't make sense, since the compiler doesn't know what type the entire expression should be.

---

There is *never* a reason to call `Html.Raw(...).ToString()`.
`Html.Raw` returns an `HtmlString` instance that wraps the original string.
The Razor page output knows not to escape `HtmlString` instances.

However, calling `HtmlString.ToString()` just returns the original `string` value again; it doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: ToString will show HTML string in the page. Like "<div></div>".ToString() will show <div></div> instead of adding div element.

Comment: I know.  I just explained why.