# How ASP.net is used before Razor was introduced

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am a little confused in how ASP.NET code is written before Razor was introduced. All I can see in many pages on the internet is how Razor is used with ASP.net. I want to know how ASP.net code is been written without Razor.

classic ASP

```
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP.NET with Razor

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP.net without Razor???
basically I want to know how people coded in ASP.net (not classic ASP) before razor was introduced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027683/html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP is usually written with `<%= %>` tags, not with `response.write()`. Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<%= "My first ASP script!" %>
</body>
</html>
```

The ASP.NET syntax is very similar, but the `<%: %>` tag was introduced to automatically HTML encode the values, similar to what Razor does. Example:

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <p>The time is <%: DateTime.Now %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

For code more complicated than just showing values, you use `<% %>` tags around server code, just as in classic ASP. Example:

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <% for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { %>
       <p>Line <%: i %></p>
     <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```