# How to change font size while using string.format in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, string.format

Referring to the question my code is

```
 @(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[1]))
```

How can i change the font size in it

Any help would be highly appreciated

**Update**

I have changed the code `@(string.Format("<div style='font-size:10px'></div> {0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[1]))`

And got the output

[image]

Comment: I did not understand the question. could you elaborate? what has a rendering engine got to do with a css rule?

Comment: see the updated code it will help you to understand

Comment: You are probably looking for Html.Raw method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027683/html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view

Comment: We need more information. What is the value of `dr[1]`? Also please include a larger selection of HTML markup, indicating exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: dr[1] is having 3 things 1. Name of the event which is in string, 2. Occurrence time which is in datetime and 3. recover time which is also is datetime i simply want to change the font size that's it

Comment: See my answer below. As far as the array itself, it sounds like you'll do better storing that info in a `Structure`.

Comment: FYI when you reply to a comment you'll want to address your recipient directly, so that he'll receive your message. You'll do so by including an `@` symbol before his username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to statically change the font size of the output, wrap it in HTML:

`<span style="font-size:2em;">@(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[1]))</span>`

Comment: I'd say this a better approach than to pass all html string to the string.Format method.

Comment: @VasileF: Take what you need; let the rest go by :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning an HTML code, then use Html.Raw

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<div style='font-size:10px'></div> {0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}", dr[1]))
```

Hope this will help you