# ?: condition in Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm Migrating an old website to ASP.Net MVC 5, I had a link like this:

```
<a href="/contact"><%=User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?"Support":"Contact Us"%></a>
```

I googled and tried several things and I ended up with the following code:

```
<a href="/contact">@if{User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){@Html.Raw("Support");}else{@HtmlRaw("Contact Us");}</a>
```

But this seems not to be the solution as it is much more complicated than the first one, while Razor is created for the simplicity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrapping your ternary expression in `@()` should work.

```
<a href="/contact">@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "Support" : "Contact Us")</a>
```

Edit:

If you need HTML elements, you can wrap your ternary expression in `@Html.Raw()`.

i.e.

```
@Html.Raw(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "<div>Support</div>" : "Contact Us")
```

Comment: As there is some html code in my strings ( for icons of font awesome) I saw that I have to use the `Hml.Raw()` but when there is no html in it. this works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Yeah that is correct. Although if you have Html elements, I believe you can just do `@Html.Raw(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "<div></div>" : "Contact Us")`, making it more readable (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8145877/5743929)).

Comment: Yeah! this is even better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The operator you are referring to is called the [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx), it is used to have inline if statements

In your example, it can be used like so

```
<a href="/contact">@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "Support" : "Contact Us")</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is more **readable**.

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
   <a href="/contact">Support</a>
}
else{
    <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
}
```