# Why Razor can not escape quotation marks as other languages do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I trying to write some code in razor but this language works differently than many others and I have no idea where is problem.

I write such code:

```
<div class="header"@(ViewBag.template_conditional_preprints.Count == 0 ? " style=\"display: none\"" : "")>
```

It should render:

```
<div class="header" style="display: none">
```

But it renders (no idea what happen):

```
<div class="header" style="&quot;display:" none&quot;="">
```

Why such strange conversion is happen and how avoid such magic conversions and render excepted string?

Comment: this is because razor by default assumes you want stuff escaped (to prevent hacking attempts). If you're sure you are okay with the string as html, then you can wrap the strings with Html.Raw().  Go here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027683/html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view

Comment: `@{ var attr = ViewBag.template_conditional_preprints.Count == 0 ? new { display: none" } : null; } <div @attr>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: that will generate a `style` attribute??

Comment: @SamAxe. Oops -`? new { style = "display: none" } : null; }`