# How can I add multiple line strings to a BulletedList web control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bulletedlist

I have a string declared such as:

```
String myString = "Operative Name: August Williams\r\n Operation Name: Bravo\r\n Operation Days: 7.00:00:00\r\n";
```

I add this to a BulletedList like so:

```
myBulletedList.Items.Add(new ListItem("myKey", myString));
```

When loaded on a web page, the line breaks seem to have no effect:

[image]

Note that its the width of the control causing line break after "Bravo".

What's causing this?

Comment: isn't it breaking before Operation Days ???

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer that its the width of the control thats causing that.

Comment: is this bullet list in a razor file or cs file?

Comment: This is in a CS file.

Comment: change the `myString` variable to what i suggested in my comment below, then when you use the bullet list in your view use the `Html.Raw()` function to print it out as html.

Comment: @AugustWilliams here is how you use Html.Raw() https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027747/5511981

Comment: use \\r\\n instead of \r\n

Comment: @AugustWilliams either one should work. If not let us know and we can try something else to help you.

Comment: Try `myBulletedList.Items.Add(new ListItem("myKey", myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of \r\n try adding    \\ r \\n

```
String myString = "Operative Name: August Williams\ \r\ \n Operation Name: Bravo\ \r\ \n Operation Days: 7.00:00:00\ \r\ \n";
```

i.e. Instead of single **\** use double of **\\** it

Comment: This is what I used to originally create the string. When I view the string in debugging, `\r\n` is what's in the string.

Comment: great...are you using @html.raw in views ??

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: okay.......single \ is escaping it.... try using "\\r\\n";...see my update answer & let me know results

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
String myString = "Operative Name: August Williams<br/> Operation Name: Bravo<br/> Operation Days: 7.00:00:00\r\n";

myBulletedList.Items.Add(new ListItem("myKey", Html.Raw(myString)));
```

when printing to the the html/razor ect. page they all follow basic html rules when displayed in the browser, meaning that all extra white space is ignored and will not be rendered. Adding a break '`<br />`' tag forces a new line when displaying the html.

Comment: is OP using razor or aspx ??

Comment: @RohitasBehera Since I used Html.Raw() I'm assuming Razor, but if his code is in the .cs file and not in a razor file then I'm pretty sure your answer is the correct one. either way both answers should work, mine will need some tweaking if his code is in .cs though.